# GUI scripting for Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, automation, scripting

Effectively, I am looking for an [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) clone for Linux.

I am aware of tools like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), [Javaauto](https://github.com/Javauto), etc, but they just won't cut it, because they rely on x, y coordinates and for example they are unable to find a window or menu item based on its title text.

I want something that I can find the window based on its title, or be able to click the button labelled 'OK'.

I have Googled and I have checked out [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/403378/autoit-script-for-linux) and [this five year old S.o question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460674/easy-to-use-autohotkey-autoit-alternatives-for-linux) - from which I shall now proceed to shamelessly copy large parts, as the OP @Xeddy made such a good job of stating the requirements.

Here’s a simple, sample script:

```
Run("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("This is some text.")
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")
WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Save")
Send("!n")
```

Run the script and you'll see Notepad open, some text appear and then close.

> Now the above example, although a bit pointless, is a demo of the sort
>   of functionality and simplicity I'm looking for. Here's an explanation
>   for those who don't speak AutoIt:
>
> ----Start of Explanation of Code ----
>
> ```
> Asks user to input some text and stores it in varInput
> Runs notepad.exe
> Waits till window exists and is active
> Sends the contents of varInput as a series of keystrokes
> Sends keystrokes to go to File -> Exit
> Waits till the "Save" window is active
> Sends some more keystrokes
>
> Shows a Message Box with some text and the contents of a variable
>
> Registers a hotkey, Win+N, which when pressed executes notepad.exe
> ```
>
> ----End of Explanation----
>
> So as you can understand, the features are quite obvious: Ability to
>   easily simulate keyboard and mouse functions, read input, process and
>   display output, execute programs, manipulate windows, register
>   hotkeys, etc.. all being done without requiring any #includes,
>   unnecessary brackets, class declarations etc. In short: Simple.

Perhaps the single greatest thing about AutoIt, which all others seem to lack is that it does not rely on x,y coordinates - one can search for a window by title (even wait for it to appear).

Plus AutoIt uses a Basic-like scripting language, with normal programming concepts like IF statements, loops, etc

Is there anything quite so powerful for Linux?

Comment: Please expand a little on why Sikuli and javaauto doesn't cut it, to further help people understand your requirements.

Comment: I can't see how to reword it. The drawbacks of others are 1) the reliance on x,y coordinates and 2) the inability to find a window or menu item based on its title text

Comment: Maybe : https://wiki.actiona.tools/doku.php?id=en:start

Comment: Alas, that too relies on X,Y coordinates. I can't tell it to `click the button labelled OK`

Comment: You mean controlling X windows, Wine apps (like Notepad under Linux), or in specific window manager (like KDE, GNOME)?

Answer (score 5):

In Linux you can use the **shell scripting** (such as [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)) along with relevant command-line tools described below.

#### `xdotool`

This is a command-line tool for faking input from the mouse and keyboard. It also supports window manager actions such as moving, activating, and other actions on windows.

Home page: [jordansissel/xdotool at GitHub](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool)

Install via: `sudo apt-get install xdotool`

Sample script example:

```
WID=$(xdotool search --name "Some Window Title")
xdotool key --window $WID --delay 500 space Tab Return Tab space Alt+n
```

Related: [How to programatically control X11 forwarded apps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219460/21471)

---

#### X utils

There are command-like tools for managing windows and display for X apps such as [`xwininfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xwininfo), [`xdpyinfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdpyinfo), [`xprop`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xprop) and other (check the `man` for more details). Along with already mentioned `xdotool`, they can be used as part of the shell script to automate and control X windows.

---

#### `expect`

There is a `expect` command line and it's used for controlling terminal processes. So if your GUI application can be controlled by the command-line and return some output, this is the tool you can use.

For example you can use mix it with `xdotool`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 360
spawn some_GUI_command & # Replace with your command.
WID=$(xdotool search --name "My GUI Title")
xdotool set_window --overrideredirect 1 $WID windowunmap $WID windowmap $WID
xdotool windowsize $WID 10 100%
xdotool behave $WID mouse-enter windowfocus windowsize --usehints 80 100% &
xdotool behave $WID mouse-leave windowsize 4 100% &
xwininfo -id $WID -tree
expect "Setup" { xdotool key --window $WID --delay 500 Tab Return }
```

<sup>Note: Above is just a pseudo-code example, I haven't tested the above code. It is just used for the reference.</sup>

---

#### AutoHotkey (AHK)

For controlling Windows apps under Linux such as `notepad.exe`, you can use [AutoHotkey (AHK)](https://autohotkey.com/) in Linux by executing it under Wine. This is how `winetricks` is using it in Linux (see [`w_ahk_do()` in `src/winetricks`](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/blob/master/src/winetricks)), e.g.

```
wine AutoHotkey.exe script.ahk
```

AutoHotkey supports scripting language and it's very underrated powerful tool. For some code examples check [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey).

---

#### AutoIt

The same as above, you can run [AutoIt under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=5480).

> The AutoIt Editor SciTE 3.3.0 runs flawlessly. Writing programms, building or compiling them is possible. I did not try to run them inside wine, as it seems senseless. Au3Check.exe, Au3Info.exe, AutoIt3.exe start without any trouble.

---

See also: [Comparison of GUI testing tools at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GUI_testing_tools)

For some Python automation libraries, see:

- [Python GUI automation library for simulating user interaction in apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42664/3474).

Answer (score 1):

Missing in the list of tools is the UI Vision tool.

> Perhaps the single greatest thing about AutoIt, which all others seem to lack is that it does not rely on x,y coordinates - one can search for a window by title (even wait for it to appear).

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) and [UI Vision](https://ui.vision/) can both do it with built-in OCR

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but very close. Great recommendations, which will help others. Welcome aboard