# Open source automation tool which can control Linux desktop application

Tags: linux, open-source, gui, automation, unix

I got a requirement where we want to control Jmeter GUI which is installed in Linux Env so I need a tool which can fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Very related [GUI scripting for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/22896/gui-scripting-for-linux)

Answer (score 1):

From AlternativeTo.net

AutoKey, previously known as AutoKey Py3, is a Python 3 port of the discontinued Small OldAutoKey iconOldAutoKey , the desktop automation utility for Linux and X11.

It allows you to manage collection of scripts, and assign abbreviations and hotkeys to these scripts allowing you to execute them on demand in whatever program you are using.

[Github - autokey/autokey: AutoKey, a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11.](https://github.com/autokey/autokey)