# python library for Linux file explorer automation

Tags: linux, python

I need a recommendation for a python library that is similar to PyAutoIt but for Linux. I have a python script that uses selenium to automatically upload photos to Instagram but am having trouble finding a library to select the file from the file explorer and click upload. Any ideas what I could use?

Comment: See also my related question[GUI scripting for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/22896/gui-scipting-for-linux). You may not get a Python solution, but you may get a solution ;-)

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/?platform=linux